# Position of an adverb in the sentences

Tags: adverbs, word-order

today I wrote a sentence like this:

> “He punched the zombies shamelessly.”

But an English man said that it was not correct, it should be:

> “He shamelessly punched the zombies.”

He could not explain why. Can anyone help me with this? Thank you a lot.

Comment: The person who told you it was wrong was mistaken. Either is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Either position of the adverb is immaterial. For more complicated sentences it can change the meaning, but in a simple sentence like this is makes no difference. It's a little old-fashioned, or literary, but you can also have:

> Shamelessly he punched the zombies

If you don't mind adding an extra word, there's at least one other option, too, though it changes the nuance significantly:

> He punched shamelessly at the zombies.

In that case, you change the object into an adverbial prepositional phrase acting as complement, which changes the meaning a little, admitting more possible understandings.

Basically, in a simple SVO sentence, you can put an adverb at the beginning, between the subject and the verb, or after the object.

Comment: Thank you a lot for this. I’m thinking that might be because he lives in a specific area and they only use adverbs that way.

Comment: @KhangB It's *possible* there's dialect considerations that make it more narrow, but I've never heard of a dialect like that.

Answer (score 0):

Adverbs of manner such as 'shamelessly' must be placed either before the verb or at the end of the clause. Your English friend is mistaken to say that only one of these is correct.

> He punched the zombies shamelessly
>
> He shamelessly punched the zombies

[Adverbs of manner](https://www.ef.co.uk/english-resources/english-grammar/adverbs-manner/)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I might meet him and show him this.